# How to transfer handsontable data to a different JavaScript on the same page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, handsontable

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](http://handsontable.com/demo/numeric.html) code of `handsontable`. As the button is pressed, the data set goes to console. I have two different pieces of JavaScript code on my webpage. One of them contains `handsontable`. **How can i transfer (dump) the data to an array belonging to a different piece of script (instead of console)?** Is there any way to create a `static` array seen to ALL pieces of scripts (like in Java)?
Here is the scheme:

```
<div id="mytable" class="handsontable"> </div>
<script>
// Here the user inserts the data to the handsontable. As she presses the button, data should go to the second piece of script.
</script>

...

<div id="target" class=""> </div>
<script>
//the target array is here, and it needs to be filled with the data from the above piece of script as the button is pressed.
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try combining the two scripts?

Comment: @Pizdy yes i have tried that. Unfortunately, it cannot be done, because the two pieces are two different JQueries. They are two different classes.

Comment: How do I open the jsfiddle?

Comment: @Kamil go to the link, it brings you to the `handsontable` website, there is a button leading to `jsfiddle`

Comment: You can create a form, and submit data using PHP to the server, and then send them back to you script, or you can use data in URL. Check this link http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/scriptpass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to do it for example:

1.) create global variable to hold the data

```
<div id="mytable" class="handsontable"> </div>

<script>
 // set data
  window.data = getCarData(); 

  $("#example1").handsontable({
     data:  window.data
  });
</script>

<div id="target" class="class"> </div>

<script>
  //get data 
  var array = window.data;
</script>
```

2.) If you use jQuery:

```
// you can bind data to element
$('table').data('key', 'value');

// and then get it
$('table').data('key');
```